# Javascript change variable depending if I'm the user

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I'm programming a game and I currently have the player speed set to a variable. What I'd like to do is use JavaScript to detect if my computer is playing the game and then change the speed. example: The default player speed is a variable that has a value of 5. If the program detects It's me that's playing the game, change the speed to 10. I would like to do this in JavaScript and I can't figure out a way to achieve this. How would I be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a value using Cookies or Web Storage and just check if it exists. If it exists, set the player speed to 10.

For example using Web Storage:
Set the value using

```
localStorage.setItem("check", "1");
```

and check if it exists using

```
if (localStorage.check == 1) {console.log("true");}
```

Some documentations:

- Cookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
- Web Storage: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Could you give an example of how this would work? How would I check if it exists?

Comment: fetch the cookie or the storage and then just check if it contains the value

Comment: I put it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will not be able to determine your Windows user name. unless it's on the current page or you do AJAX calls to a server-side script to get more information.

But you can do it manually: save in session storage or local storage and then check if something exists, it will save on your computer so it will know:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('status','loggedIn')
```

and then:

```
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('status') != null))
//redirect to page
}
else{
    //show validation message
}
```